# Piping data to plot and points function in base R with `|>`

Tags: r

I'm wondering how to pipe data to make a plot and add points with the native R pipe operator `|>`

```
dtf = data.frame(pop1 = 1:10, pop2 = 2:11, gen = 1:10)
dtf |>
  (\(dt) plot(x = dt[,"gen"], y = dt[,"pop1"]))() |>
  (\(dt) points(x = dt[,"gen"], y = dt[,"pop2"]))()
```

The lines below work:

```
dtf |>
      (\(dt) plot(x = dt[,"gen"], y = dt[,"pop1"]))()
```

But when adding the points, R 'forgot' that it was piping the data since there is no output from plot to pass it to points. Is there a way to 'continue' the pipe to feed the points function?

I figured out that this would work, but kind of misses the purpose of the pipe operator:

```
dtf |>
  (function(dt) {
    plot(x = dt[,"gen"], 
         y = dt[,"pop1"], pch = 19, col = "red")
    points(x = dt[,"gen"], 
           y = dt[,"pop2"], pch = 19, col = "black") 
    }
   )()
```

Comment: I'm not sure it "misses the point" of the pipe operator. It's just the base R plotting functions were not written in a way to benefit from piping. Code needs to be designed around that philosophy to maximally benefit. Just like you can't use `|>` or `%>%` with ggplot layers, you need to use `+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipe operator is supposed to make code simpler and easier to read, but when working with functions like `plot()` and `points()` that aren't designed with piping in mind, it tends to make things more obscure.  You're better off just using functions like that in separate statements:

```
plot(pop1 ~ gen, pch = 19, col = "red", data = dtf)
points(pop2 ~ gen, pch = 19, col = "black", data = dtf)
```

or

```
with(dtf, {
  plot(pop1 ~ gen, pch = 19, col = "red")
  points(pop2 ~ gen, pch = 19, col = "black")
})
```

Comment: Indeed, that makes sense. I was just thinking that maybe I missed something in using the pipe that prevented me from adding points.